# Obtain selected text from IFRAME using Rangy

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rangy

I am trying to get selected text of Iframe using Rangy using this function;

```
function getSelectedText() {
   var iframe = document.getElementById("CustomeHTMLViewer");
   var iframeWin = iframe.contentDocument ? iframe.contentDocument.defaultView : iframe.contentWindow;
   var sel = rangy.getSelection(iframeWin);
   return sel;
}
```

**This code is not working; how can I get selected text of an Iframe?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rangy has a convenience method for this: `rangy.getIframeSelection()`. Example:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("CustomeHTMLViewer");
var sel = rangy.getIframeSelection(iframe);
```

To get hold of the selected text, call `toString()` on the selection:

```
var selectedText = sel.toString();
alert(selectedText);
```

Rangy allows an iframe element to be passed directly into `rangy.getSelection()`.

Having said all that, there doesn't actually seem to be anything wrong with your original code.

Comment: This is my complete code
<script src="../Scripts/plugins/rangy-1.2.3/rangy-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/plugins/rangy-1.2.3/rangy-selectionsaverestore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function () {..rangy.init();...}

    function getSelectedText() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("CustomeHTMLViewer");
        var sel = rangy.getIframeSelection(iframe);**//this is not working**
        var selectedText = sel.toString();        alert(selectedText);       
    }
</script>

Comment: Thanks for ur time !! `function doSelect() {
            var frame = document.getElementById("CustomeHTMLViewer");
            var doc = frame.contentWindow.document;
            var selection = rangy.getSelection(frame.contentWindow);
            selection = rangy.getSelection(frame.contentWindow);
            alert(selection);
        }` now its working

Comment: @TimDown is it possible to copy rangy html selections to clipboard using `.execCommand('copy')` ?

Comment: @Blowsie: Rangy on wraps the browser's native selection so it's down to the browser.